# how to upload image with button into canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have problem in my study. I want to make a custom made shirt website. I have a beginner code as below

If you know how to upload image with button into shirt canvas and change the shirt color with a button too, please teach me, thanks before and sorry for my bad english text^^

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Canvas example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if (!element || !element.getContext) {
      return;
    }

    var context = element.getContext('2d');
    if (!context || !context.drawImage) {
       return;
    }
    context.fillStyle   = '#CC5422'; // set canvas background color
    context.fillRect  (0,   0, 350, 350);  // now fill the canvas 

    // create amd draw the branding image for the qr-code
    var Shirt = new Image();
    Shirt.addEventListener('load', function () {
       context.drawImage(this, 35, 25, 275, 275);
    },false);
    Shirt.src = "men_shirt_front.png";
  },false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:35px;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="350">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element.
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are trying to learn, you can start using the following script,

TO UPLOAD FILES USING UPLOAD-AT-CLICK

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
     /**
     * UPLOAD SCRIPT 
     * This script uses the UploadAtClick library to upload files on a webserver folder
     * using a PHP script ("upload/upload.php")
     * Project homepage: http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
     */
upclick(
{
element: uploader,
action: 'upload/upload.php', 
onstart:
function(filename)
{
      //alert('Start upload: '+filename);
},
oncomplete:
function(response_data) 
{
      // Check upload Status
if (response_data != "FAIL") {                
        // Draw the picture into Canvas     
        // "response_data" contains the image file name returned from the PHP script
displayPicture("upload/" + response_data);
}
}
});
```

UPLOAD PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$ok = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
 // This message will be passed to 'oncomplete' function
echo $ok ? $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] : "FAIL"; 
?>
```

Comment: Always welcome to answer others questions. If you are satisfied with this answer kindly accept the answer by ticking it. Thanks.

Comment: I have found a specific answer,thanks all ^^

http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/10/upload-images-from-the-user-hard-driveto-an-html5-canvas-easel-js-application/